# Как сделать выборку постов по дате в WordPress

Tags: wordpress, дата, wp-query

У меня стоит задача: есть 2  (месяц и год) дата с которой брать публикацию первую и 2  (месяц и год) последней публикации. Мне нужно вывести все материалы в этом интервале. Было бы круто если эти селекты заменить просто на два, такие как при добавлении публикации в WordPress где там все в куче можна выбрать и день и месяц и год. Спасибо за помощь.

```
function true_filter_by_date($where = '') {
    $from = '2012-11-15'; 
    $to = '2012-12-24';
    $where .= " AND post_date >= '$from' AND post_date <= '$to'";
    return $where;
} 

add_filter('posts_where', 'true_filter_by_date'); 
 
$params = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1 
);

$q = new WP_Query($params);

while($q->have_posts()) {
    $q->the_post();
    echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a>';
}

wp_reset_postdata();
 
remove_filter('posts_where', 'true_filter_by_date');
```

Answer (score 0):

Для работы с датой есть специальный класс [WP_Date_Query](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_date_query)

```
$params = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'date_query' => array(
        'before' => array( 'year' => 2012, 'month' => 12, 'day' => 24 ),
        'after' => array( array( 'year' => 2012, 'month' => 11, 'day' => 15 ),
        'inclusive' => true, // включительно
    ),
);

$q = new WP_Query($params);
```

Comment: А как сделать так, чтобы в <select> отображались месяц и года из публикаций.
Например первая публикация у меня Март 2020 года, вот у меня в первом селекте можна выбрать минимальным значением март 2020 а последняя публикация в июне 2021, чтобы она была во втром селекте последней?

Comment: @СергейГуртовой какой еще select ? Вы о чем вообще? у Вас в вопросе только запрос на wp-query